# Put whole ComboBox in TableView column

Tags: java, combobox, tableview, javafx-8, editor

[The Java Swing run image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQCkw.jpg)[The JavaFx run image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq0hV.jpg)I need to add whole ComboBox to TableView column, Not OservableArrayList in JavaFx, Because I set autocomplete property to the ComboBox like java swing, I tried it using java swing and it work successfully, but didn't work in javafx

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    TableView table = new TableView();
    ObservableList <String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();

    list.add("Product One");
    list.add("Product Two");
    list.add("Product Three");
    list.add("Product Four");

    table.setEditable(true);
    comboBox.setEditable(true);

    comboBox.setItems(list);

    TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(comboBox.getEditor(), comboBox.getItems());

    TableColumn productName = new TableColumn("Product Name");
    TableColumn productCode = new TableColumn("Product Code");

    productName.setEditable(true);
    productName.setCellValueFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(list));

    productName.setMinWidth(100);
    productCode.setMinWidth(100);

    table.getColumns().addAll(productName, productCode);
    table.getItems().add(new Object [] {null, null});

    root.getChildren().add(table);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: why to you repost the exact same question under a different tag (vs. editing [the old](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58206475/203657))? Your only change is to use the correct parameter ...

Comment: Ok thanks, I forgot to remove the old one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you have to set ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn for cellFactory not for cellValueFactory.

If you want to set a separate comboBox in the TableCell, you need to include it using cell factory. Notice that each TableCell will have its own ComboBox (not a single comboBox that is passed to all cells).

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    list.add("Product One");
    list.add("Product Two");
    list.add("Product Three");
    list.add("Product Four");

    TableView table = new TableView();
    table.setEditable(true);
    TableColumn productName = new TableColumn("Product Name");
    TableColumn productCode = new TableColumn("Product Code");

    productName.setEditable(true);
    //productName.setCellValueFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(list));
    productName.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell call(TableColumn param) {
            return new TableCell() {
                private ComboBox comboBox;

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (!empty) {
                        setGraphic(getComboBox());
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }

                public ComboBox getComboBox() {
                    if (comboBox == null) {
                        comboBox = new ComboBox();
                        comboBox.setEditable(true);
                        comboBox.setItems(list);
                        TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(comboBox.getEditor(), comboBox.getItems());
                    }
                    return comboBox;
                }
            };
        }
    });

    productName.setMinWidth(100);
    productCode.setMinWidth(100);

    table.getColumns().addAll(productName, productCode);
    table.getItems().add(new Object[]{null, null});

    root.getChildren().add(table);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: don't re-invent the wheel as an octagon (or worse ;) - afaics, you are missing to set the value of the combo to item